# How do I remove the useraction=commit from PayPal Express Checkout?

Tags: magento, url, checkout, paypal

I am using Magento 1.9 and standard PayPal Modules and want to know how do I remove the useraction=commit from PayPal Express Checkout url? Because I dont want that the button wears the caption "pay now". Hope u can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved this problem as follows:

firstly I've copyied app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php to app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php after that I've edited this file and commented out the following line (line 624):

```
    if ($this->isOrderReviewStepDisabled()) {
        //$params['useraction'] = 'commit';
    }
```